# Linux installing mpi4py error - exit status 1

Tags: python, linux, mpi4py

When i try to install mpi4py using this command

```
pip3 install mpi4py
```

and also tried,

```
sudo pip3 install mpi4py
```

and i always get this error:

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-widf03/mpi4py/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-widf03/mpi4py/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-Y4v7zm/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python2.7/mpi4py Check the logs for full command output.

I have looked at many forms but did not find anything useful.

Comment: You can try to use pip instead of pip3.

Comment: I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

First, run this command:

```
sudo apt install libopenmpi-dev
```

Later run this again:

```
pip3 install mpi4py
```

This does not give any error for me.